Suppose $\phi(a) \geq 0$ for every state $\phi$ of $\mathcal{A}$. Can we conclude that $a\geq 0$.
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $C^{\ast}$-algebra and $ a \in \mathcal{A}$ be a nonzero self adjoint element.

Suppose $\phi(a) \geq 0$ for every state $\phi$ of $\mathcal{A}$. Can we conclude that $a\geq 0$.


The problem can be reduced to the $C^*$-algebra generated by $a.$

Yes, we can. Assume first that $A = C^\ast(a)$. As $a$ is self-adjoint, we have $C^\ast(a) = C_0(\Omega)$ for some locally compact Hausdorff $\Omega$ (in fact, $\Omega = \sigma(a) \setminus \{0\}$). Evaluation at any point $x \in \Omega$ is a state, whence $a$, as a function on $\Omega$, is non-negative. Thus, $a$ is positive as an element of $A$.
In general, any state on $C^\ast(a)$ can be extended to a state on $A$, so $\varphi(a) \geq 0$ for any state $\varphi$ on $A$ implies $\psi(a) \geq 0$ for any state $\psi$ on $C^\ast(a)$, whence the result follows.
